# Is it possible to create a nested object and a relationship to it to another nested object in a single operation?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create an object using a writable nested ModelSerializer

The parent object A has two nested objects B and C through nested serializers. B has a ForeignKey to C.

Since its a nested relationship, I wrote a custom create() method.

I want to be able to find a way to create A, its two nested obects B and C and the relationship between B and C in a single POST. The thing is that I don't see a way to reference either B or C to one another since they don't yet exist in the database. And any reference or RelatedField won't pass through the serializer validation.

Thanks in advance for your help.